# check the checkbox which is reside in the textbox - asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have created a checkbox using textbox in asp.net mvc 4 on view page like this.

```
@Html.TextBox("SomeID", "SomeValue" ,new { type = "Checkbox" })
```

now based on some condition, I would like to check this checkbox.

How could it be possible?

I have tried  this,

```
@Html.TextBox("SomeID", "SomeValue" ,new { type = "Checkbox", value = "true" })
```

but it is not working.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the way you are doing it does not make sense.  If you want to use a checkbox then use @lagerone answer. If you need conditional check uncheck do something like following

```
@{
    var someCondition = true;
}
@Html.CheckBox("test", someCondition)
```

The way you are rendering it, you can achieve it by following code.

```
@{
    var someCondition = false;
}
@if (someCondition)
{
    @Html.TextBox("SomeID", "SomeValue", new {type = "Checkbox", @checked = ""})
}else
{
    @Html.TextBox("SomeID", "SomeValue", new { type = "Checkbox" })
}
```

Use your logic to assign some value to `someCodition`

Answer (score 0):

TextBox != CheckBox

You could try

```
@Html.CheckBox("MyChecBox",true)
```

Comment: Hi,thnx but i would like to retrieve checkbox value in textbox form so thats why I have used this way. its working normally but I just want to check the checkbox.